# Can't CD to directory inside of root

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod, cd, chown

I am currently creating an application that requires separate users running duplicate programs. They cannot run under root because of security reasons, so they are initiated by a Java app that I am working on, and I am starting them with runuser -l. However, I cannot cd into a directory, even though it is owned by the user, and the user has 770 permissions in the folder.

Here's what I'm running:

```
runuser -l lp1 -c 'java \-jar /root/Desktop/workspace/LitePanel/servers/server1/server.jar \-Xms1024M nogui'
```

And the output of this is:

```
runuser: warning: cannot change directory to /root/Desktop/workspace/LitePanel/bin/servers/server1/: Permission denied
```

Here's an ls -all:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 Jan 30 14:03 .
drwxr-xr-x. 7 root root 4096 Jan 30 14:02 ..
drwxrwx---. 2 lp1  lp1  4096 Jan 31 03:07 server1
```

Inside the directory:

```
drwxrwx---. 2 lp1  lp1     4096 Jan 31 03:07 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root    4096 Jan 30 14:03 ..
-rwxrwx---. 1 lp1  lp1  9170551 Jan 31 03:07 server.jar
```

And here's /etc/passwd:

```
lp1:x:501:501::/root/Desktop/workspace/LitePanel/bin/servers/server1/:/bin/false
```

Anyone know why this is happening? It looks like the user has the necessary permissions to do this.

Comment: Are you sure the java app is running as lp1? maybe try executing 'whoami' in the java app to make sure that it is running as the user

Comment: @Xeli I am sure that it is running as lp1, because I get the same if I run it in the terminal as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have said that the directory itself has permissions `770` and is owned by the user, but what about its parents? I believe the `cd` command will need at least read access (and possibly execute) on the parent directories.

Comment: I have permissions to all sub-directories, same issue.